# Python3 Selenium Fill Username and Password in Popup Dialog

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.5

I want to access a website using Python3-Selenium. However, in order to access my target website, I have to pass and authentication page.

For example, the URL target website that I want to access is https://target_website.com. Whereas the URL of the authentication page is https://example.example.com/ab/cd/ef

Here is the sample of the page:

[image]

As you may see from the figure above, I have to:

1. fill username
2. fill password
3. click login

Tried the following code, but did not work.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('path_to_exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 600)

browser.get('https://target_website.com')
wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
browser.get('https://<username>:<password>@example.example.com/ab/cd/ef')
```

Tried the following code, still did not work.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('path_to_exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 600)

browser.get('https://target_website.com')
wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
browser.get('https://<username>:<password>@example.example.com')
```

Lastly, I tried the following code, but again it did not work.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('path_to_exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 600)

browser.get('https://target_website.com')
wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
alert.authenticate('<username>', '<password>')
alert.accept()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox('path_to_exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.get('https://target_website.com')
alert = wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert.send_keys('username' + Keys.TAB + 'password')
alert.accept()
```

Note that this approach works in `Firefox` only

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately, I do not have Firefox. Strangely, I may skip the authentication page if I am using IE. However, my code does not work in IE11, I kept getting the following error message: `NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to find element on closed window`

Comment: tried it using Firefox. This part `alert.send_keys('username')` worked. This part `alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)` worked. However, this part `alert.send_keys('password')` did not work. After `alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)` the cursor has been moved to the password field, however, when I executed the `alert.send_keys('password')` it wrote down the password to the username field. So the username field consisted of `usernamepassword`. Any idea how to deal with this? Thanks a ton!

Comment: try `alert.send_keys('username' + Keys.TAB + 'password')`. This should work.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! Please edit your post, and I will mark it as the right answer. Thanks a lot!